# Highlight CSS Grid

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-grid

I have CSS Grid:

```
<div style="display:grid;
            grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows:repeat(5, 1fr);
            align-items: center;
            justify-items: center;"
     sc-part-of="placeholder rendering"
     class="scEnabledChrome">
</div>
```

when I inspect grid in Chrome DevTools I have next highlighting effect:
[image]

How can I achieve similar effect using CSS or JavaScript?
I want to have ability to show/hide lines that divide grid.

Comment: dashed border? ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif dashed or solid, it doesn't matter. I don't see what element and what style I should add to achieve highlighting of grid itself.

Comment: **Not possible!** CSS-Grid rows/columns are **not elements** and so cannot be selected with CSS. There are extensions for this,

Comment: @Paulie_D May be some hack to make browser think that Chrome DevTools are opened and element is inspected? (For me it will be enough to do only for Chrome)

Comment: If there were its off-topic as too broad for SO.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't get why it is too broad. I have concrete task: show grid lines in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea using gradient to have similar effect (but without the dashes). You simply need to adjust the values of the gradient to make it the same as the repeat:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  background: 
   repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0,transparent calc(100%/5 - 1px),#000 calc(100%/5 - 1px),#000 calc(100%/5)),
   repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0,transparent calc(100%/5 - 1px),#000 calc(100%/5 - 1px),#000 calc(100%/5));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You may also consider CSS variable to make it easy:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--c,5), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--r,5), 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  background: 
   repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0,transparent calc(100%/var(--c,5) - 1px),#000 calc(100%/var(--c,5) - 1px),#000 calc(100%/var(--c,5))),
   repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0,transparent calc(100%/var(--r,5) - 1px),#000 calc(100%/var(--r,5) - 1px),#000 calc(100%/var(--r,5)));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:3;--r:4"></div>
```

Comment: Nice idea, I will try it. Only one problem that I can have with it: I don't know grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows values in advance. I will need converter grid-template-columns >  repeating-linear-gradient(to right...) and grid-template-rows > repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom...)

Comment: @Anton you can rely on CSS variable, I have added an example

Comment: @Anton I have updated the calculation, I was wrong doing + 1px, it sould be -1px ... each step should have a total for 100%/5 and not 100%/5 + 1px