# How to give grid columns and rows a border?

Tags: html, css

basically title. Here is the code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: red;
}

#gameboard {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "gameboard"></div>
    </body>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js.js"></script>
</html>
```

If you go to a full page in the snippet, you will see a grid that is 8x8 - how do I give each column and row a black border (kind of like a checker game board has)?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: last snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51860729/8620333